# Google Chrome и IE11 дают ошибку при скачивании текстового файла

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer, iis

При переносе веб-сервера ASP.Net Web Forms приложения с одного физ.сервера на другой у пользователей Google Chrome и Internet Explorer 11 пропала возможность скачивать файлы. Каждый раз файл появляется в списке загрузок, но не скачивается, а рядом с именем файла в списке загрузок, возникает надпись "Ошибка: Ошибка сети" в Chrome, а в IE11 "Не удалось скачать myfilename.txt".
И на старом и на новом сервере, Windows Server 2008 R2, но IIS немного отличается по пунктам меню. С браузером Mozila FireFox проблем с скачиванием файла нет.

Для загрузки файла клиенту использовался следующий метод

```
protected void UnloadFileToClient(string fullfilename)
{
    if (fullfilename.Length > 0)
    {
        System.IO.Stream iStream = null;

        // Buffer to read 10K bytes in chunk:
        byte[] buffer = new Byte[10000];

        // Length of the file:
        int length;

        // Total bytes to read:
        long dataToRead;

        // Identify the file to download including its path.
        //        string filepath = "DownloadFileName";

        // Identify the file name.
        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fullfilename);

        try
        {
            // Open the file.
            iStream = new System.IO.FileStream(fullfilename, System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                        System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read);


            // Total bytes to read:
            dataToRead = iStream.Length;

            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";                 
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);


            // Read the bytes.
            while (dataToRead > 0)
            {
                // Verify that the client is connected.
                if (Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    // Read the data in buffer.
                    length = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);

                    // Write the data to the current output stream.
                    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);

                    // Flush the data to the HTML output.
                    Response.Flush();

                    buffer = new Byte[10000];
                    dataToRead = dataToRead - length;
                }
                else
                {
                    //prevent infinite loop if user disconnects
                    dataToRead = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Trap the error, if any.
            Response.Write("Error : " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (iStream != null)
            {
                //Close the file.
                iStream.Close();
            }
            Response.Close();
        }
    }
```

В попытках решить проблему вносил следующие изменения

```
Response.Clear(); //что-то чистим
Response.ClearHeaders(); //еще что-то чистим
Response.ContentType = "text/plain"; //указываем конкретный MIME-тип
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
```

и

```
Response.End(); //явно указываем, что мы закончили
Response.Close();
```

Но не помогает. Поведение ни Chrome, ни FireFox не меняется.

В настройках "Типы MIME" ASP-приложения в IIS -

`.txt      text/plain     Унаследовано`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось нужно добавить длину файла в HttmlResponse перед началом передачи данных

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", dataToRead.ToString());
```